# Java granular debug message for different modules

Tags: java, debugging, logging, messaging

I know the common way to handle `critical/error/debug/warning/info` message is through a message/logging system. Then one can use a flag to switch the messages to be printed out.

Sometimes the debug message can be overwhelming. What if I need more control on the debug message by modules? How can I toggle debug messages by modules? Is it possible with typical message/logging system? Or what's a better way doing it?

I used to use `#define MODULE1_DEBUG 1/0` in C++. Then write a bunch of

```
#ifdef MODULE1_DEBUG 
cout << "my debug message for module1" << endl;
#endif
```

This way I can toggle the #define in each module's header to enable the debug message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can control the debug messages by modules. Please find below a sample configuration file to control the messages in log4j.

```
log4j.appender.MY_LOGGER=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.MY_LOGGER.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.MY_LOGGER.File=/logs/my.log
log4j.appender.MY_LOGGER.Append=true
log4j.additivity.MY_LOGGER.Append=false
log4j.appender.MY_LOGGER.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.MY_LOGGER.layout.ConversionPattern=[MY] %d [%t] %-5p %C - %m%n

log4j.logger.com.example.dao=DEBUG, MY_LOGGER
log4j.logger.com.example.action=INFO, MY_LOGGER
log4j.logger.com.example.controller=WARN, MY_LOGGER
```

This would set the logging level in com.example.dao package at DEBUG, com.example.action at INFO and com.example.controller at WARN.

You can have different properties for different modules even. Just create more LOGGER instance, as below

```
    log4j.appender.MY2_LOGGER=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
    log4j.appender.MY2_LOGGER.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
    log4j.appender.MY2_LOGGER.File=/logs/my2.log
    log4j.appender.MY2_LOGGER.Append=true
    log4j.additivity.MY2_LOGGER.Append=false
    log4j.appender.MY2_LOGGER.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.MY2_LOGGER.layout.ConversionPattern=[MY2] %d [%t] %-5p %C - %m%n

    log4j.logger.com.example.my2.controller=WARN, MY2_LOGGER
```

http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/